# Matching data in 2 different linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list

So i have a program that is supposed to match babysitters to people based on inputted info. All the info for both parties is saved in linked lists. Is is possible to match data from the babysitter linked-list to the parent linked-list? And also make it output something like "__ possible matched for you"

Comment: Java or Javascript? They're not the same, or even related.

Comment: its java I think it auto added that tag or something

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "match". It also depends a lot on how the data is stored in the linked list.

Comment: 1. I have no interest to know and there is no meaning to tell about babysitter.  Keep the question to-point please. 2. What is the content of the linked list?  3.  What is the definition of "match data"?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have much data, the simple but inefficient way of solving the problem is:

```
boolean matches(Person person, BabySitter babySitter) {
    // implement a logic that returns whether babySitter and person match
    return person.getNumberOfChildren() <= babySitter.getMaximumNumberOfChildren() &&
        babySitter.getWorkingDays().containsAll(person.needsBabySitterForDays());
}

for (Person person: people) {
    for (BabySitter babySitter: babySitters) {
        if (matches(person, babySitter)) {
            System.out.println("Babysitter " + babySitter + " is recommended to " + person);
        }
    }
}
```

The above algorithm takes O(b * p) time where b = number of babysitters, p = number of people. So for large b and p, it is slow.

Based on the logic of `matches` you could achieve a solution close to O(b + p) by a reverse index. So if you have 10.000 babysitters and 10.000 people this optimized solution would run pretty quickly while the above algorithm would take a couple of seconds.

Comment: You should put a `break` statement in the inner loop. Once it has found a match, there's no need to keep searching.

Comment: @Barmar it's not clear from the OP, whether a single or multiple recommendations are expected.

Comment: It would be matching number of kids and days of the week you need baby sitting to number of kids you can babysit and number of work days available during week

Comment: @M.Srom how many objects do you have in each list? you could fill in the matches method to make the above solution work.

Comment: Well the amount of objects depends on the user input. The objects are filled with user inputted info (e.g first name, last name, number of kids, days of week). im just trying to match parents and clients by the number of kids and days of week

Comment: @M.Srom I've updated the code example to show you how you should go about implementing the `matches()` method.

Comment: @DavidFrank Yea i get the jist of the code. The only thing im kinda unsure about is where to write the matches() method and the for loops

Comment: @M.Srom That really depends on the structure of your application. You should definitely place it where you make use of it, eg. you first get data from the user, then run this code. I really cannot give a more in depth advice without knowing your code.

Comment: @DavidFrank Alright thanks, I'll play around with it and see.